# I am converting a json file returned from the server into perl data structures

Tags: json, perl, perl-data-structures

I am able to convert a hard coded json string into perl hashes however if i want to convert a complete json file into perl data structures which can be parsed later in any manner, I am getting  the folloring error. 
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at json_vellai.pl line 9

```
use JSON::PP;
$json= JSON::PP->new()

$json = $json->allow_singlequote([$enable]);

open (FH, "jsonsample.doc") or die "could not open the file\n";

#$fileContents = do { local $/;<FH>};

@fileContents = <FH>;

#print @fileContents;

$str = $json->allow_barekey->decode(@filecontents);

foreach $t (keys %$str)

{


print "\n $t -- $str->{$t}";

}
```

This is how my code looks .. plz help me out

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `decode` doesn't want a list, it wants a scalar string.

You could slurp the file:

```
undef $/;
$fileContents = <FH>;
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to localise changes to Perl's special global variables, e.g.: `my $fileContents = do { local($/); <FH> };`  Note that local implicitly undef's its arguments.